# Power BI embed exit full screen

Tags: javascript, wordpress, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am adding power JS bi embed to WordPress posts, I am using `report.fullscreen()` to  make it full screen but how can I add a button to the iframe when it is full screen to allow users to easily click on the button and exit full screen mode ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger `report.exitFullscreen()` from your button.
Make sure you put the button over the report(z index)